# Why does __call__ returned values get garbage collected when calling a class twice: SomeClass()()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a simple example of a class:

```
class Class1:
    def __call__(self):
        self.x = input('x > ')
        return self.x
    def print_x(self):
        print(self.x)
```

1)Now when I try to call this class the way ahead:

```
Class1()()
Class1().print_x()  # Return self.x
```

I get an error raised: `AttributeError: 'Class1' object has no attribute 'x'`
It's like self.x from get garbage collected before it jumps to the next line of code.

2) Now when I try to call the class in such way:

```
# Prints input value correctly
c = Class1()
c()
c.print_x()
```

The value is printed correctly.
Can someone please explain what is going on in the first one? Why does it garbage collect before it jumps to Class1().print_x()
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I know there are ways to make it work. I am trying to understand what is going on behind the scenes on both the first and second call. Why does the first one raises the error. But the second one works fine.

Comment: `Class1().print_x()` -> This creates new object Class1(), where `x` is not defined yet. As solution, create constructor `__init__` and define `x` there.

Comment: But why does that the second example can prints the value of x.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what happens:

```py
Class1()()  # create a new class instance and call it, which sets the attribute "x"
            # unfortunately, the instance was never given a name, sooo...
            # ...now the instance is gone, as you don't have any way to access it 

Class1().print_x()  # create a new class instance and try to access its attribute "x"
                    # ... which was never set for this instance

c = Class1()  # create a new class instance and give it a name
c()  # call it, which sets the attribute "x"
c.print_x()  # access this object's attribute "x"
```

Comment: This is a good explanation. The important part is that when the OP writes `Class1()`, it is **not** running the `__call__` function. It is creating an instance. The `__call__` function is only executed when an *instance* is called.

Comment: Aha ! That's what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: As a side note, if you want a class method to be run when you call the class and create an instance, you can use `__init__` or `__new__` (not interchangeably, they both have different purposes).

Answer (score 0):

This solution works:

```
c = Class1()   # create object of type Class1 and store it to c (Note: __call__ isn't called, self.x doesn't exist)
c()            # call the object (__call__ is called, self.x is created)
c.print_x()    # print self.x, OK
```

This solution doesn't:

```
Class1()()           # create object of type Class1 and call it (Note: the object isn't stored to any variable, so it's garbage collected)
Class1().print_x()   # create *ANOTHER* object of type Class1 and call print_x() <-- this causes error, because __call__ wasn't called before and self.x doesn't exist
```

As solution, you can define your class this way:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def __call__(self):
        self.x = input('x > ')
        return self.x
    def print_x(self):
        print(self.x)
```

Then

```
Class1().print_x()
```

Prints:

```
0
```

Comment: I know that's a way to make it work. I am trying to understand what is going on behind the scenes on both the first and second call. Why does the first one raises the error. But the second one works fine. Thanks

Comment: @Kornee See the comments I've put next to the code samples. Basically, in the solution that doesn't work you create two different objects - and `__init__` is different from `__call__`